# Moment.js months difference

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've been using moment.js for a short while now, and it's made date manipulation a lot easier but I have a specific case that is failing, and I can't see why.

When calculating the diff between today (31st October 2013) and the 1st February 2014, the months diff comes back as 2, although there are 3 complete months and one day between the two dates.

Diff between 31st October and 31st January works fine: 3 months and zero days.

```
var mStartDate = moment([ periodStartDate.getFullYear(), periodStartDate.getMonth(), periodStartDate.getDate() ]);
var mTermDate = moment([ someDate.getFullYear(), someDate.getMonth(), someDate.getDate() ]);

console.log('periodStartDate: ' + periodStartDate);
console.log('someDate: ' + someDate);

// Years
var yearsDiff = mTermDate.diff(mStartDate, 'years');

// Months
var monthsDiff = mTermDate.diff(mStartDate, 'months', true);
```

The console logs the following:

```
periodStartDate: Thu Oct 31 2013 11:13:51 GMT+0000 (GMT)
someDate: Sat Feb 01 2014 11:13:51 GMT+0000 (GMT)
monthsDiff: 2
```

If I pass true as the boolean not to round, the months diff is

```
monthsDiff: 2.983050847457627
```

Is this just a bug in Moment.js.diff()? Every single one of my other test cases pass successfully.

Comment: I've encountered this on version 2.2.1 - I can see it happening with 2.4.0 as well

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I think this has to do with the 'special handling' as described in [The Fine Manual](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/):

> It is optimized to ensure that two months with the same date are
>   always a whole number apart.
>
> So Jan 15 to Feb 15 should be exactly 1 month.
>
> Feb 28 to Mar 28 should be exactly 1 month.
>
> Feb 28 2011 to Feb 28 2012 should be exactly 1 year.

Moment.js applies this special handling when dealing with `31 Jan` and `31 Oct` (having the same day):

```
// 31 Oct 2013 - 1 Feb 2014
> moment([2014, 1, 1]).diff(moment([2013, 9, 31]), 'months', true)
2.983050847457627

// 31 Oct 2013 - 31 Jan 2014
> moment([2014, 0, 31]).diff(moment([2013, 9, 31]), 'months', true)
3

// 31 Oct 2013 - 30 Jan 2014
> moment([2014, 0, 30]).diff(moment([2013, 9, 31]), 'months', true)
2.967741935483871
```

So the `2.98` value is correct, it's just that the second example turns the result into a 'calender months' difference.

(as for rounding down to 2, that's also documented on the same page)

Comment: Thanks Robert.

But isn't it weird that the value goes up (when calculating difference with 31/01) compared to 30/01, then down again?
I would expect something like 2.967, then 3, then 3.02 or something like that.

If there are 3 complete months between two dates, how can there be less when I add one day?

The other thing I do after all this, is that I display the difference in a "X months and Y days" manner. So... if there are 2 months, that takes me to the 31/12, and then there's 32 days to reach the 1st Feb.

Comment: @Khain because the days value is the same it clamps the value to a whole number (that's the "special handling"). For the other dates, it doesn't clamp and uses the exact (floating point) value.

Comment: @robertklep do you mean moment([2013, 10, 31]).diff ? May be a typo?

Comment: @LPG you mean to create an instance representing Oct 31st? That should be `moment([2013, 9, 31])` (since months are 0-indexed, so 0 is January, 1 is February, etc).

Answer (score 24):

I went a different route trying to get the difference between two months

```
function getAbsoluteMonths(momentDate) {
  var months = Number(momentDate.format("MM"));
  var years = Number(momentDate.format("YYYY"));
  return months + (years * 12);
}

var startMonths = getAbsoluteMonths(start);
var endMonths = getAbsoluteMonths(end);

var monthDifference = endMonths - startMonths;
```

This made sense to me and since moment is doing some strange things with diff I just decided to make it clear what my result will be.

Comment: from the latest moment library, just return d.month() + d.year()*12

Comment: Why multiply the years by 12? wouldn't this accomplish the same result without that?

Comment: I did 12 because if our start is 04-2017 and end is 01-2018  if you only took the months + the year would give you 2021 - 2019 = 4 which I'm looking for 9.

Answer (score 17):

Simple And Easy Solution with correct value difference between two months if you are using moment Library

```
  const monthDifference =  moment(new Date(endDate)).diff(new Date(startDate), 'months', true);
```

If you want to add the number of days in endDate

```
 const monthDifference = moment(new Date(endDate.add(1, 'days'))).diff(new Date(startDate), 'months', true);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try out this `method`;

```
function getMonthDifference(startDate, endDate) {
    const increment = startDate.getMonth() === endDate.getMonth() ? 2 : 1;
    const diff = moment(endDate).diff(moment(startDate), 'months', true);
    return Math.ceil(diff) + increment;    // this increment is opitional and totally depends on your need.
}
```

Comment: this returns 15 months between `startDate: '2022-07-01T00:00:00.000-07:00', endDate: '2023-07-27T00:00:00.000-07:00'`