# Calculate current age in months

Tags: javascript

I need the age in months by a given birthday and the current date:

I found this one, which gives me the age in years:

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    age = age * 12 + m;
    return age;
}
```

But I need the age in months. A five year old child should get the result of 60; if the child is 5 years and 3 months old it should give the result of 63.

http://jsfiddle.net/n33RJ/567/

This doesn't give me the correct value.

Comment: keep a counter and add one month to birthdate until it is greater than today

Comment: The code you posted gives me months. And the fiddle you just posted also works for me.

Comment: check this out .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705003/moment-js-months-difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the function you posted does return the number of months.

Copied:

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    age = age * 12 + m;
    return age;
}
```

I ran `getAge('1990-May-16')` and it returned 305, which is 25 years and 5 months.

Your jsfiddle uses an invalid [dateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) -- `getAge("10.07.14")`

Comment: Ok -- I edited my answer. I didn't notice the jsfiddle

Comment: @user3848987 - The fiddle gives 12 months. What do you expect it to give with the input of 10.07.2014?

Comment: `getAge("2014-10-07")` should give me `15 months`, shouldn't it?

Comment: According to [the w3c date and time spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), "2014-10-07" is interpreted as "YYYY-MM-DD", not "YYYY-DD-MM"). That date is interpreted as October 7, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Use your year * 12 and then add the month difference. If we have Febuary 2011 but the child is born April 2010, you get 1*12+(-2)=10 Months

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = (today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear())*12+(today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth());
    return age;
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the fiddle in my post. This does the same, but you see in the console, that the value is incorrect.

Comment: Have you used the correct syntax? Its getAge('YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: And please change back your question, it is out of context if you keep it like its now

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birth = new Date(dateString);
    var years = today.getFullYear() - birth.getFullYear();
    var months = today.getMonth() - birth.getMonth();
    return years * 12 - months;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another using `getTime` for precision...

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birth = new Date(dateString);
    var timeDiff = today.getTime() - birth.getTime();
    var yearDiff = timeDiff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 365.25;
    return yearDiff * 12;
}
```