# get number of months and remaining days between two dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for how to get number of months and remaining days between 2 dates.

Example: `in = 2017-04-10, out = 2017-05-15`

output should be **1 month, 5 days**

-

this is what i tried:
number of months

```
var numofmonths = out_month - in_month + (12 * (out_year - in_year));
if(out_day < in_day){
 numofmonths--;
}
```

and days

```
var numofdays (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

output is like *1 month, 35 days.*

how can I remove the days of the month if there is month, and show only remaining days?

Comment: A month is 31, 30 or 28 days?

Comment: You should decide how many days does your app consider to be a month?

Comment: number of **months** and remaining **days** between two dates in javascript @mplungjan

Comment: That depends on what a month is. From the 15th of Feb 2016 to the 15th of March 2016 - Is that one month?

Comment: month can be any

Comment: So no proper answer - read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705003/moment-js-months-difference

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
let getDiff = (inDate, outDate) => {
    let years, months, days;
    
    inDate = moment(inDate);
    outDate = moment(outDate);
    
    years = outDate.diff(inDate, 'year');
    inDate.add(years, 'years');

    months = outDate.diff(inDate, 'months');
    inDate.add(months, 'months');

    days = outDate.diff(inDate, 'days');

    return {
      days: days,
      months: months,
      years: years
    };
  },
  getDiffFormatted = d => `${d.years} years, ${d.months} month, ${d.days} days`;

// in = 2017-04-10 and out = 2017-05-15
let diff1 = getDiff('2017-04-10', '2017-05-15');
console.log('diff1:', getDiffFormatted(diff1));

// in = 2017-04-10 and out = 2017-05-09
let diff2 = getDiff('2017-04-10', '2017-05-09');
console.log('diff2:', getDiffFormatted(diff2));

// in = 2017-04-10 and out = 2017-06-15
let diff3 = getDiff('2017-04-10', '2017-06-15');
console.log('diff3:', getDiffFormatted(diff3));

// in = 2015-01-22 and out = 2017-06-15
let diff4 = getDiff('2015-01-22', '2017-06-15');
console.log('diff4:', getDiffFormatted(diff4));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is not working if it is more than 2 months.

Comment: if `in = 2017-04-10 and out = 2017-06-15` result: 2 month, 66 days.

Comment: Based on @mplungjan comment I have updated the answer to get the number of months and remaining days between 2 dates using Moment.js

Comment: @Elyor can you give a check to my answer please? Thanks