# Transform days into weeks, months, years with Moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two dates, **from** and **to** and I want to compute the interval between them.

I managed to compute the days by doing so:

```
const interval = Math.floor((Date.parse(to) - Date.parse(from)) / 86400000);
```

it works fine but in my case I need to be sure if the interval is equal to a month (which can have between 28 and 31 days). I think that Moment.js can be used for this but I have no idea how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `moment.js` for that - and its `diff()` method, in particular. Quoting [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/):

> To get the difference in another unit of measurement, pass that
>   measurement as the second argument.

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]); 
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

> The supported measurements are `years`, `months`,
>   `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds`. For ease of development, the
>   singular forms are supported as of 2.0.0. Units of measurement other
>   than milliseconds are available in version 1.1.1.

Be aware of some [peculiarities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705003/moment-js-months-difference?rq=1), however, and make sure you do understand how exactly the difference is calculated.