# Exact Month difference between two dates - MomentJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I need to know the difference between months, but I cannot perform this calculation based on the days, considering that there are months with only 28 days.

I really need to bring the difference between months.

> Format: YYYY/DD/MM
>
> Old: 2019/01/19
>
> New: 2020/03/19
>
> Between: 14

```
Example 01:
Old Date: 19/03/2020
New Date: 31/03/2020
Between: 0

Example: 02:
Old Date: 19/03/2020
New Date: 01/04/2020
Between: 1

Example: 03:
Old Date: 19/03/2020
New Date: 30/04/2020
Between: 1

Example: 04:
Old Date: 19/03/2020
New Date: 01/05/2020
Between: 2

Example: 05:
Old Date: 19/03/2020
New Date: 01/05/2021
Between: 14
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705003/moment-js-months-difference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moment.js months difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705003/moment-js-months-difference)

Comment: @Christian The results are coming in decimal, that is, they calculate based on the days ... I needed to calculate the months.

Comment: I'm update examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can discard the days count by using momentjs `.startOf('month')` date modifier and then compare the days using `.diff()`:

```js
const getDate = (date) => moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').startOf('month')
const diff = Math.abs(getDate('19/03/2020').diff(getDate('01/05/2021'), 'months'));

console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ocurred error in moment: 
const diff = Math.abs(moment(firstDate).startOf('month').diff(moment(secondDate).startOf('month'),'months'))

Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in
an upcoming major release.

Comment: @rbrt Make sure that you specify the date format when parsing a date with moment, for example: moment('19/03/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Comment: if I specify it, it gives me an incorrect value. first: 2020/03/12 second: 2021/12/01, result: 219

Comment: I managed with this format:

moment(firstExpiration, 'YYYY-MM-DD')