# How to calculate the difference between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, momentjs

All I am trying to do is this.

Let's say in Google Sheets, I have a page which has the following columns:

In column I3 I have the date of 11/30/19.
In column J3, I have Today's date of 4/30/20.
I want to be able to calculate the difference between these two dates and tell me how many months has it been since 11/30/19.

[image]

Currently, I think the code is working somewhat but the result I get is:

[20-05-02 01:43:18:650 MDT] 5 months, 6 days

[20-05-02 01:43:18:656 MDT] 5 months, 6 days

[20-05-02 01:43:18:660 MDT] 5 months, 6 days

But the date calculations are still wrong. For example from Jan 1st - Jan 25, 2020, it shows 5 month and 6 days.

Also the loop I have inside Filter 1, is just calculating the first available date and then it does this three times instead of going to the next record and calculate.

I have the following code so far:

```js
function myFunction() {
   
}

var moment = Moment.load();

/**
 * @summary gets date difference
 * @param {Date} startDate
 * @param {Date} endDate
 * @returns {string}
 */
function getDuration(startDate, endDate) {
   const start = moment(startDate);
   const end = moment(endDate);
   const units = ['years', 'months', 'days'];
   const lastIndex = units.length - 1;
   const parts = units
     .map((unit,i) => {
       const diff = Math.floor(end.diff(start, unit, true));
       if (diff > 0 || i === lastIndex) {
         end.subtract(unit, diff);
         return `${diff} ${unit}`;
       }     
     })
     .filter(Boolean);
   return parts.join(', '); 
}


function Filter2() { // Calculate the Time
   const spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const sheets = spread.getSheets();
   const [ sheet_1, sheet_2 ] = sheets;
   const row = sheet_1.getRange("A:M");
   const arr_col = sheet_1.getRange("I3:I50"); 
   const lastSeen_col = sheet_1.getRange("J3:J50");  
   const startDate = arr_col.getValue();
   
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  
   var headerRowNumber = 2;
   var rows = sheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();
   var filter = rows.filter(row => row[9] !== '');
   // var digest = filter[0][9];
   
  for(var i=0;i<filter.length; i++){
     var res = getDuration(startDate, lastSeen_col);
      Logger.log(res); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: I would simply recommend some date library like date-fns: https://date-fns.org/v1.28.5/docs/differenceInMonths
Edit: Moment can also do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705003/moment-js-months-difference

Comment: @Oleg Valter i did use moment but not sure what else to do from here. My goal is to say ok if its been 5 months from 11/30/19 till today, send an email to user listed in google sheets. But i am not sure how to extract the month from the result of this date calculation.

Comment: @mrRay - that's not my comment) I've been drafting you an answer - you likely pass an invalid argument to `getDuration` - `startDate` is an instance of `Range` instead of the expected `Date`

Comment: My pleasure - take a look at the answer, although I don't use Moment library so I can't describe you the inner workings of it, the problem is likely to be the type mismatch

Comment: @mrRay - please, use the "@{Username}" to ping us that there is still an issue and, in case there is a new problem, don't reedit question, start a new one and link to this (this ensures that people who come in later will see the relevant issue). I only chanced at the update since I occasionally review answers... I will edit the question accordingly. As for the updated issue - there is likely to be a problem with your loop, more on that later

Comment: @mrRay - actually, I think the best course of action is making a rollback. Please, post the update as a separate question (no need for reference except for linking to this one), and I'll rollback that one (ping me, please with @). As for the loop - my answer considered `startDate` to be in the loop, but in your case it is fixed at `11/26/2019` (I3). And now you have the same problem with `lastSeen_col` as it should be a `Date` obtained via `getValue` / `getValues`, but it is just the `Range` in your code

Comment: Hi @mrRay - do you still face the problem and have you seen my previous comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why Dec, 31 1969**

31st of December, 1969 in GMT-7 timezone offset is January 1st, 1970 00:00:00 UTC, which is the [unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Therefore it is likely to be caused by an invalid date format passed to the `Moment` class instance.

**Problem**

`getRange()` method call returns an instance of `Range` from which you have to extract value via `getValue()` / `getValues()` before being able to use it. With that in mind, let's track what's going on in your script:

1. `var ArrRow = sheet_1.getRange("I3:I")` returns an instance of `Range`
2. `mydata1` is defined somewhere globally (let's assume it holds an instance of `Date`)
3. `getDuration` is thus called like this: `getDuration( <Range>, <Date> )`
4. `startDate` and `endDate` are respectively an instance of `Range` and `Date`
5. `start` and `end` hold results of invoking the `moment` factory that [creates a wrapper](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) around `Date` object.

Step 5 is most likely to be the culprit, as per Moment library docs, `moment()` can accept `String`, `Number`, `Date` instances as well as format options, but `start` recieves a `Range` instance instead.

**Possible solution**

First, you need to ensure you pass in correct types (this why a lot of folks prefer TypeScript - if that's not your cup of tea, at least start using [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/index.html) - it will save you a ton of debug time).

I don't know how big the `I3:I` range is, so I assumed from the context that it is a single cell containing start date. Also note that I removed the `var sld = new Date(dateString)` assignment since you return a human readable string from `getDuration()` of format `Y years, M months, D days` which is not a `dateString` that `Date` constructor can accept.

Additionally, I would suggest changing `forEach()` to `map()` method for cleaner and less side effect prone code. General rule of thumb is that if input and output are of the same type, you likely want to use a mapping function.

```
function myFunction() {
   Filter2();
}

function Filter2() {
   const spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const sheets = spread.getSheets();

   const [ sheet_1, sheet_2 ] = sheets;

   const arr_col = sheet_1.getRange("I3:I"); 

   const startDate = arr_col.getValue();

   var dateString = getDuration(startDate, mydata1);

   Logger.log(dateString);
}

var moment = Moment.load();

/**
 * @summary gets date difference
 * @param {Date} startDate
 * @param {Date} endDate
 * @returns {string}
 */
function getDuration(startDate, endDate) {
   const start = moment(startDate);
   const end = moment(endDate);

   const units = ['years', 'months', 'days'];
   const lastIndex = units.length - 1;

   const parts = units
     .map((unit,i) => {
       const diff = Math.floor(end.diff(start, unit, true));

       if (diff > 5 || i === lastIndex) {
         end.subtract(unit, diff);

         return `${diff} ${unit}`;
       }     

     })
     .filter(Boolean);


   return parts.join(', '); 
}
```

**Notes**

1. The answer assumes you use V8 engine (if you don't - [switch to it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration), old one will be deprecated some time in the future, and as a bonus you get to use all the juciest language features [well, most of them]).

**References**

1. `Date` constructor [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) on MDN
2. `Range` class [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
3. `getValue()` method [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
4. `getValues()` method [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Oleg Valter THANK YOUUUUU SO MUCH My Friend. This works Like a Charm. Thank you so much. If I am not asking for too much, can I ask how can I get this code to run for the entire sheet as long as there are data in the rows? Also, can I get another column's value in the same row? For example, in row 1, after calculating the dates in column b1 and c1, there is a email in column d1 which I need to grab if the difference between b1 and c1 is 5 months.

Comment: No problem; as for the extra questions - yes and yes in short. To get another column, you can use the `offset()` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) - but that will be slow in the loop. Instead, grab all rows needed (just expand `getRange()`), then get all values with `getValues()` - this will return an Array of Arrays where each top lvl item represents a row, and its items - cell values. From there you can simply reference values by their indices (e.g. `values[5][2]` for date and `values[5][N]` for email, etc)

Comment: Regarding "types", I find it useful to include a hint of the data type in the variable name if it matters, e.g. `startDate` if it's a Date or `startTimestamp` if it's a string, `startTimeValue` if it's a time value, etc. They can be abbreviated too: `startD`, `startTS`, `startTV`. Not perfect but helpful, as is good docs. ;-)

Comment: Useful, but a bit too excessive for my taste :) I found out that the way that works for me is just using VSCode (inbuilt TS with type inference is a bliss) with occasional hints to help it infer types (especially for factory functions)